# Can't configure PHP in my computer. Can you check what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: php

I'm going to show you what I've done step-by-step and the issue I'm facing in the end. I have configured PHP in my computer this way:

1. download php from php.net (this part I know I did correctly);
2. extract all the zip file downloaded to a specific file;
3. I set the environment variables like this:

[image: path followed]

4. Set it as I should:

[image: Set up]

5. Can't find this path here:

[image: Command Prompt]

Comment: Have you tried logging off and on again?

Comment: restart your computer.

Comment: Close down the Command Prompt and reopen it - it needs to re-read the env vars.

Comment: Dear stranger, thank you for your prompt response. I did restart and it is now working!

Comment: @LielFridman, I have restarted my computer and it did work!

Comment: @AmineKOUIS I did that and it's now working! Thank you for your help. Stackoverflow community is the best out there!

Comment: Gabriel you are welcome :)

Comment: It worked, @halfer , appreciate your help!